# Return from __call__ immediately if a value gets changed in the class

Tags: python, function, class, self

I want to return to the main function whenever value of a is set to 1 by any of the functions(func1,func2,func3) called in the class. Can anyone help me in solving this?I need to return immediately before calling rest of the functions when value is set. I have attached a code snippet for reference.

```py
    class Property:
    
        def __init__(self):
            ## initializing the attribute
            self.a = 0
        def __call__(self, val):
            self.func1(val)
            self.func2(val)
            self.func3(val)
        def func1(self,value):
            if value==20:
                self.a = 1
                return
            print("all okay in func1")
        def func2(self,value):
            if value==40:
               self.a = 1
               return
            print("all okay in func2")
        def func3(self,value):
            if value==60:
               self.a = 1
               return
            print("all okay in func3")
     
     def main():            
         obj = Property()
         obj(20)
```

Comment: I mean the simplest thing is just to check the value of `self.a` after each function call inside `__call__`, and return if it is 1. Are you looking for something fancier or more automatic than that? You could also wrap all the function calls in `__call__` in a "try" block, and throw some special exception whenever you set `self.a` to 1.

Comment: Yes,say I have 20 function calls.In that case after each call i need to check "a" value which I thought can be done automatically.I mean is there property/function which I can implement so that it keeps monitoring my "a" value and returns when changes detected?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could write e.g. another member function to check "a" and throw an exception if it is 1, and just call this function as the first thing you do in all your other 20 functions. Then wrap the try/catch block around all your function calls.

Comment: you can use the [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator to check to what value a give attribute is set to by making getter/setter for it

Answer (score 3):

How's this?

```
class Property:

    def __init__(self):
        ## initializing the attribute
        self.a = 0
    def set_a_to_1_and_raise(self):
        self.a = 1
        throw MyCustomException 
    def __call__(self, val):
        try:
            self.func1(val)
            self.func2(val)
            self.func3(val)
        except MyCustomException:
            return
    def func1(self,value):
        if value==20:
            self.set_a_to_1_and_raise()
        print("all okay in func1")
    def func2(self,value):
        if value==40:
           self.set_a_to_1_and_raise()
        print("all okay in func2")
    def func3(self,value):
        if value==60:
           self.set_a_to_1_and_raise()
        print("all okay in func3")
```

Edit: Added @tdelaney's nice suggestion regarding the name of the function  `self.set_a_to_1_and_raise()` to make it obvious that it raises an exception when you call it.

Comment: This is a solution, of course, this seems like *major* code smell to me, but it does do what the OP wants.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I had a similar answer except that it just created a setter for `a` instead of a different function. What I didn't like about that was its not obvious why something raises when it gets a 1. This example, with a name change like `set_a_and_raise` makes it explicit. This seems like a normal use of an exception - it moves control up a few rungs in the stack but is just internal to the implementation.

Comment: Thank you @Ben Farmer. The solution is useful for my problem statement.

Comment: Np. I just added an alternative solution based on @Copperfields suggestion to use property decorators. It's much the same as this solution, i.e. based on throwing exceptions, but has some syntax changes that you might prefer or find useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297052/1447953.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283404/1447953) @Copperfield had the suggestion of using the Python @property decorators to do this, which could be handy for some applications. This saves you from having to changing the code where you assign `self.a = 1`, and it will just "automatically" notice whenever you happen to make such an assignment. It's a bit more "under the hood", i.e. less transparent to readers of the code, but could still be useful:

```
class Property:

    def __init__(self):
        ## initializing the attribute (Note change to _a, not a)
        self._a = 0
    def __call__(self, val):
        try:
            self.func1(val)
            self.func2(val)
            self.func3(val)
        except MyCustomException:
            return
    def func1(self,value):
        if value==20:
            self.a = 1
        print("all okay in func1")
    def func2(self,value):
        if value==40:
           self.a = 1
        print("all okay in func2")
    def func3(self,value):
        if value==60:
           self.a = 1
        print("all okay in func3")

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, new_value):
        self._a = new_value
        if self._a == 1:
            throw MyCustomException
```

What is happening here is that we have specified `a` as a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). On the surface it works just like a normal member variable in how you assign and access it, however with the special `@a.setter` decorator we can define a custom function that runs whenever you set its value. So here we can make it check what value is being assigned, and throw a `MyCustomException` if that value is 1, which we can then catch after skipping the functions that you didn't want to run.